# IBOutlet is nil

Tags: swift, iboutlet, xcode8.2

I have created a standard outlet for a view that will hold different information based on the button selected on the previous screen.

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelView: UIView!
```

It shows it is connected in both the story board view and on the code itself, however, every time I get to any reference to the labelView such as:

```
if detail.description == "About"
{
   labelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Then the app crashes out with:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have tried everything I can think of or read on the internet:

- Removed and replaced the connection
- Deleted the derived data folder like one post suggested
- Created a reference to self.view to force it to load
- Moved it to `viewDidAppear`
- Moved it to `viewWillAppear`
- Moved it to `viewDidLoad` (which is where it is currently being
  called)

I am sure at this point that the answer is rather simple and I am just completely missing it.

Comment: Can you please show the backtrace so we can get a better idea of what's happening? Exactly which line is it crashing on?

Comment: I'm sorry if I ask you a simple question: are you sure you have the crash in that line? Have you try to put a breakpoint and proceed step by step to see if is it really the crash line?

Comment: Are you removing the view from its superview at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see where the outlet is being set to nil, try this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelView: UIView? {
    didSet {
        print("labelView: \(labelView)")
    }
}
```

You should see it set to an initial value when the view is loaded. If it then gets set to `nil`, put a breakpoint on the `print` and your should be able to see from the backtrace where it's happening.

Comment: Adding that and checking through the back trace (again) I finally found the simple and stupid error.  I was modifying a previous project and missed a call to a function that was referencing the view from the segue before the view did load, therefore nil.  I do feel very foolish now.

Answer (score 0):

Views are lazy initialized. In case you are calling the affected line of code *before* `viewDidLoad()` in the views life cycle, try to access `view`in advance:

```
if detail.description == "About" {
    _ = self.view
    labelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```