# iOS IBOutlet is non-nil, somehow being scavenged to nil

Tags: ios, crash, iboutlet, forced-unwrapping

TL;DR: I have an `IBOutlet` (`UILabel`) that is properly connected in Storyboard. Accessing (unwrapping) it works fine in `viewDidLoad()` ... but a few seconds later its value is nil. A watchpoint says that the outlet changes right after a call to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, *but...* a `print()` call at the end of `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` shows it non-nil.

This is very similar to [IBOutlet is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812047/iboutlet-is-nil) but his solution (track value with `didSet()`) did not work. (There are many related posts but all had trivial solutions.)

What I have done:

- Reconnected the outlet to the Label — from both sides
- Deleted the Label and reconnected it
- Cleaned the project
- Deleted the DerivedData
- Quit and restarted Xcode
- Quit and restarted my Mac
- Added a `didSet()` method to the outlet.

  - It triggers during `viewDidLoad()` and shows a non-nil value.
  - In `viewDidLoad()` I set its text value with no problem
  - It does *not* trigger before the nil-unwrapping crash
- Added a watchpoint to the variable.

  - This *does* trigger before crash (right after `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and shows the following:

[image: screenshot of Xcode debugger]

As mentioned before, at exit of the most recent method call before the watchpoint (`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`) the outlet is non-nil.

These crashes seem always to involve subviews of a particular superview. I added a watchpoint to the superview's outlet but it never triggers.

What could be inciting my code to let go of this weak reference?

Comment: You'll need to show some code to get any help. Trim it down to only what's needed to reproduce the issue. See [mcve]

Comment: The project has almost 1000 files, and the relevant ViewController has almost 1000 lines of code. (Yes, I did split it up into separate extensions for all the protocol conformances.)  I will edit my posting but you will see that sample code does not help. The existing (very comprehensive) description should suffice. (For someone who knows more about iOS garbage collection than I do.)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I was clobbering the relevant views.

Well, the best way to find your own answer is to ask someone else. Thanks to @DonMag, I was preparing more traces, breakpoints, and screen shots. I noticed this method (added to fix another bug, of course):

[image: screen shot showing me removingFromSuperview the very views that were nil]

Of course, the two views that were becoming nil were subviews of `centralOverlay`. Ones I wanted to keep.

So I guess my answer was similar to that of [IBOutlet is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812047/iboutlet-is-nil) — pilot error — except the `didSet()` handler did not solve the mystery.